# Axios post not sending data at all... setting form-post header doesn't work correctly

Tags: axios

can't figure this one out, seen a couple of answers saying that the object is encoded as JSON, which is fine however this isn't the case either.

```
axios.post('/api/calculate', {
    term: 12,
    borrowAmount: 1000,
    depositPercent: 40
}, {
    headers: { 'X-CSRF-TOKEN': window.csrf_token }
})
.then(response => {
    this.response = response.data;
});
```

From my understanding the **second** parameter in the `post` method is the data, which will be converted to JSON, however this isn't happening and `$_POST` is simply empty...

Even if this did work, it's a bit crap really as I have then got to account for receiving a JSON string within my end point instead of just an `$_POST` array like a normal form...

Comment: does the request arrive to your server and do you see a (i guess) code 200? The only thing i can suggest is to try with the simplest possible request without the header to see if something changes and go on from there

Comment: @JohnSmith I have tried to passing `{ test: 'hello' }` to keep it simple and this doesn't work, I have also removed the header. And yes I get a 200 response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, found a solution to this issue. Basically it's due to Axios not posting the data with either of the following content types:

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data-encoded

Instead it's using `application/json`.

This code will fix the issue:

```
if (empty($_POST)) {
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```